# How to quantify the impact of a variable in a VAR model equation?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

Given a VAR model (the equations that make the model, coefficient significance and the adjusted $R^2$ value for each equation), is there a way to calculate the impact of a variable over the other?

Comment: Try impulse-response functions (see how a shock to variable 1 affects variable 2 over time), perhaps also Granger causality (test whether the information contained in variable 1 helps predict variable 2 when historical information contained in variable 1 is given).